# Report doesn't show data in VS2008 on Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, reporting-services

I have to build a custom report that takes the orderlines for each order with the client's name,address and username on the report.

When I make a simple query like:

```
SELECT FilteredSalesOrder.*, FilteredAccount.* 
FROM FilteredSalesOrder INNER JOIN FilteredAccount 
ON FilteredSalesOrder.customerid = FilteredAccount.accountid
```

I retrieve data but only for a single line. When there are more, the preview shows nothing.
which is not that big of a problem because I only need it for 1 order at a time.

So for my OrderReport I need all the OrderLines for each order. The report is printed out per Order not for multiple orders at the same time.
It will look something like this:
[image]

I just joined 5 tables from which I need data in my Order Report.

```
SELECT FilteredSalesOrder.*, FilteredAccount.*, FilteredSalesOrderDetail.*, FilteredSystemUser.*, FilteredProduct.*
FROM ((((FilteredSalesOrder INNER JOIN FilteredAccount 
ON FilteredSalesOrder.customerid = FilteredAccount.accountid) INNER JOIN FilteredSalesOrderDetail 
ON FilteredSalesOrderDetail.salesorderid = FilteredSalesOrder.salesorderid) INNER JOIN FilteredProduct
ON FilteredProduct.productid = FilteredSalesOrderDetail.productid) INNER JOIN FilteredSystemUser
ON FilteredSystemUser.systemuserid = FilteredSalesOrder.ownerid)
```

So to summarize:

- Is my SQL query correct?
- When I upload a simple report it gives me the error rsInvalidDataSourceReference. I know what this issue means but what do I need to do to solve it.
- How do I make sure that in the report, the orderline table keeps on growing as needed to include all the orderlines?

Comment: You've put 3 questions in one, which makes it difficult for people to answer effectively. It would be better to ask each one separately, with the appropriate details for each issue. As a general suggestion, forget the report for now and focus on writing a query that returns the correct data. No one can tell you if your query is correct without information about the table structures, the relationships (foreign keys) between them and the data. And you should avoid using `SELECT *` in queries because it will cause problems if (when) you change the columns in a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Is my SQL query correct?

It returned an error because the query returned more than 665 Columns and apparently SQL can't handle that.

- When I upload a simple report it gives me the error
  rsInvalidDataSourceReference. I know what this issue means, but
  what do I need to do to solve it.

This was solved by adjusting the connection string when you open the report in notepad++ you can alter it to match your production environment.

- How do I make sure that in the report, the orderline table keeps on
  growing as needed to include all the orderlines?

That is something that the report handles itself when you make the report using the report wizard of Visual Studio 2008 on the SQL Server. If you drag and drop fields from your dataset. The report will only take the first record it finds.